# Protocol for Ethernet over USB?

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, windows-xp

I use USB to connect to modem on my computer. As mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB#Protocols). There are about four main protocols which a USB cable to provide ethernet-style networking. I'm curious to know which one do I use? How can I check it?

Comment: It will be in the driver, deep in the software.. or in the hardwares firmware. The only way to inspect it is to sniff packets on the USB line using specialised equipment.. or try and debug the code with a assembler freeze.. not simple.. essentially you want to reverse engineer. Why do you want to know anyway?

Comment: While reading about it, I was just curious if it is possible to check that. And I use PPPoE protocol to connect to ISP. Does it mean if I use USB, PPPoE gets emulated through one of those four protocols?

Answer (score 1):

You could inspect the USB bus on Linux.

The USB bus is modeled and mounted in `/dev/bus/usb/`.
You could check if you see anything in `/proc/bus/usb/devices` that may indicate the protocol used.

In case you're a Windows user only, I can't help you. But I believe there are means to inspect the USB bus on Windows as well.